# How to Fix: Digital Ocean SSL Cert hosted subdomains not pulling in all resources

Tags: ssl, nginx, digital-ocean, lets-encrypt, certbot

I've hosted 3 web-app personal projects on a Digital Ocean droplet located under /var/www/.

The projects are dave-barrett.com, basketbrawwl.dave-barrett.com, evolve.dave-barrett.com

So 2 are served under subdomains of my portfolio site. The portfolio site loads fine, the subdomains are loading under HTTPS but have issues loading in many of the resources and I'm having a difficult time identifying whether it's angular.js related, NGINX config issues, or SSL cert issues.

I just recently added SSL Certificates for HTTPS security for the first time. I understand that each sub-domain needs it's own cert, but when I created them via LetsEcrypt's CertBot it seemed that it was creating a single cert for me that would cover each of those (though I could be mistaken).

I've tried npm install on each project, rebuilding with gulp, then restarting the node servers.

I've tried various root var/www/etc paths under both the 443 server config and port 80 configs.

My NGINX config file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name dave-barrett.com;

    #Redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS with a 301 Moved Permanently response.
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name basketbrawwl.dave-barrett.com;

    #Redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS with a 301 Moved Permanently response.
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8083;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name evolve.dave-barrett.com;

    #Redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS with a 301 Moved Permanently response.
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8085;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name dave-barrett.com;
    root /var/www/dave-barrett.com/dist;


    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt//live/dave-barrett.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt//live/dave-barrett.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    # Diffie-Hellman parameter for DHE ciphersuites, recommended 2048 bits
    # ssl_dhparam /path/to/dhparam.pem;

    # intermediate configuration. tweak to your needs.
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    # HSTS (ngx_http_headers_module is required) (15768000 seconds = 6 months)
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

    resolver 8.8.8.8; #points to google's DNS address which is quite safe
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name basketbrawwl.dave-barrett.com;
    root /var/www/basketbrawwl-app/public;


    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt//live/dave-barrett.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt//live/dave-barrett.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    # Diffie-Hellman parameter for DHE ciphersuites, recommended 2048 bits
    # ssl_dhparam /path/to/dhparam.pem;

    # intermediate configuration. tweak to your needs.
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    # HSTS (ngx_http_headers_module is required) (15768000 seconds = 6 months)
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

    resolver 8.8.8.8; #points to google's DNS address which is quite safe
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name evolve.dave-barrett.com;
    root /var/www/Personal-Project/dist;


    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt//live/dave-barrett.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt//live/dave-barrett.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    # Diffie-Hellman parameter for DHE ciphersuites, recommended 2048 bits
    # ssl_dhparam /path/to/dhparam.pem;

    # intermediate configuration. tweak to your needs.
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    # HSTS (ngx_http_headers_module is required) (15768000 seconds = 6 months)
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

    resolver 8.8.8.8; #points to google's DNS address which is quite safe
}
```

Screenshot of Console for Evolve.dave-barrett.com:
https://i.imgur.com/s8R9WKb.png
(site visibly loads, but connection to my postgres DB doesn't seem to work)

Screenshot of Console for basketbrawwl.dave-barrett.com:
https://i.imgur.com/T1Y5Gaw.png
(hardly anything visibly loads)

These each were working before I decided I needed to go add SSL Certificates! I haven't changed any of the code in the sites.

Comment: Does each subdomain really need its own cert? I have 3 domains under one cert with LetsEncrypt. Your two subdomains do show "connection not secure" in Firefox, so apparently your cert is only on the main domain so far. I would go ahead and add SSL to those. The way I added domains to my certificate is: 

`sudo certbot certonly -d domain.com -d www.domain.com -d otherdomain.com -d www.otherdomain.com --expand`

Comment: If you're expanding a certificate this way to add domains or subdomains, you have to specify `domain.com` and also `www.domain.com`. (Everything you want covered can be added with a `-d` switch before it.) Yours would be something like `sudo certbot certonly -d dave-barrett.com -d www.dave-barrett.com -d evolve.dave-barrett.com -d www.evolve.dave-barrett.com -d basketbrawwl.dave-barrett.com -d www.basketbrawwl.dave-barrett.com --expand`. (Expand to add new domains)

Comment: Thank you @Bman70! It looks like it's opened a new walkthrough to set up SSL for the other subdomains which I hadn't gone through before. I found some other info on creating a .ini file with access token from DigitalOcean and got it working. Now just sorting angular.js issues lol